# Switch between cellular and WiFi programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

**How does the [Speedify app](https://speedify.com/) switch between cellular and WiFi programmatically within the app?**

With the Speedify app on, I "prioritized Cellular", ran a speed test, which showed the WiFi symbol on the whole time.

[image]

Then checked my cellular usage, and sure enough 111 MB was used even though wifi was never off.

[image]

I have read through [NEVPNManager docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager), which is used in the app, but can't seem to find anything. Perhaps [SCNetworkConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkconfiguration) is used?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a static IP but don't put in any router IP as described here
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6448960
I think this can be achieved in code using Apple NetService framework

Comment: hi @Mosbah, that make sense - removing the default gateway (router IP) would result in loss of WiFi and force the phone to use cellular. However that seems destructive, as the phone would have to reconfigure the WiFi interface again. I just turned on Speedify again, and saw that it does not change the WiFi IP.